# I am stuck when trying to implement code to update recyclerview after search view displays databse infromation

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Hvaing problems trying to implement the correct code for update feature in my app using recyclerview and a search view, all the videos i've seen done use the method i have.

i have tried implementing an onlongclicklistener to begin with the long press stage of updating specific recyclerview details, but cannot implement onclicklistener inside a public static class to begin with.

Some background on my app, it submits customer details, then you switch to a new activity with a search view which displays firebase data in a recyclerview, and i am looking to be able to search for a customer, then long click on the data to be able to update specific data for that customer.

```
public static class CustomerNameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        View mView;


        public CustomerNameViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDetails(String userCustomerName, String userNumber, String userBikeArrival, String userBikeCollection,
                               String userpartQ, String userlabourQ, String userrepairQ, String userFinalPrice,
                               String userInStock, String userNeedOrdered, String userAdditionalInfo, String userBikeType)
        {

            TextView customername =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomerName);
            TextView contactnumber =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
            TextView bikearrival = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewBikeArrival);
            TextView bikecollection = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewBikeCollection);
            TextView partQ =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPartQ);
            TextView labourQ =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLabourQ);
            TextView repairQ =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRepairQ);
            TextView finalprice = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFinalPrice);
            TextView instock =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewInStock);
            TextView needordered =  mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNeedOrdered);
            TextView additionalinformation = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAdditionalInfo);
            TextView biketype = mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewBikeType);


            customername.setText(userCustomerName);
            contactnumber.setText(userNumber);
            bikearrival.setText(userBikeArrival);
            bikecollection.setText(userBikeCollection);
            partQ.setText(userpartQ);
            labourQ.setText(userlabourQ);
            repairQ.setText(userrepairQ);
            finalprice.setText(userFinalPrice);
            instock.setText(userInStock);
            needordered.setText(userNeedOrdered);
            additionalinformation.setText(userAdditionalInfo);
            biketype.setText(userBikeType);

        }
```

as a beginner i am sure that the update code must be used within the view holder but again, i am completely lost at this part

Comment: What do you mean through "updating specific recyclerview details"?

Comment: @AlexMamo for instance the recyclerview pulls about 12 fields from the database to be displayed upon a search (customer details) i am looking to long click the customer item on the recyclerview and display a dialog box with update values such as final price, quoted price? as these values may change after work is completed and be different to the initial input values at the start, if that makes sense